# Can't use round function of python properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I am getting output `15.36` but I want only `15`. I am using round function e.g `round(15.36,2)` but still getting the same result.

Comment: The second argument is the number of decimal digits, (that is, digits *right* of the `.`) -- try `round(15.36, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

The documentation explains the arguments for the [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function pretty well:

> `round(number[, ndigits])`
>
> Return number **rounded to *ndigits* precision after the decimal point**. If *ndigits* is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its input.

So if you want to round to the nearest integer just use it without the second argument:

```
>>> round(15.36)
15
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the  [round function in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

`round(number, ndigits)`

So, for your example use `round(15.36,0)`